# Visual Studio connect to Azure SQL Database

Tags: database, azure, visual-studio

[Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/free-sql-db-free-account-how-to-deploy?view=azuresql-db) is the cloud version of SQL Server.

[Add a connection to Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/azure-sql-database-add-connected-service?view=vs-2022)

[image]

In the given demonstration, it's a C# WebApplication. How do I connect it with a C++ project? Like what SSMS does for SQL Server?

Comment: Could you please give clarification about your expectation? Are you expecting in [this](https://i.imgur.com/Ft3tyWl.png) way?

Answer (score 1):

**Primary method:**

To connect Azure SQL database to C++ project Go to Tools select `Connect to Database` option.

[image]

Provide the required details of Azure SQL server   and test the connection. Set firewall rule in SQL server Networking tab.

[image]

The SQL database will connect successfully.

[image]

**Secondary Method:**

To connect Azure SQL database to C++ project Go to Tools select `Add SQL Server` option.

[image]

Connect to your Azure account and select your SQL database as mentioned in the below image:

[image]

Set Firewall rule if needed.

[image]

The SQL database will connect successfully.

[image]